# Providing a trusted root CA to THTTPClient in Delphi 11

Tags: http, delphi, ssl-certificate

We want to securely connect to an internal webserver with `THTTPClient` (Delphi 11).

The webserver is using a TLS certificate signed by the (private) company root CA.

**How can we pass the (trusted) root CA cert to `THTTPClient` so that it can validate the webserver's certificate?**

With Indy there was the option of setting `SSLOptions.RootCertFile` in `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to pass trusted root certs.

I only found the `ValidateServerCertificateCallback` on `THTTPClient` but that would require us to implement the validation from scratch and again require a crypto library like OpenSSL. Or is there a framework from Delphi with which we can validate a `TCertificate` against a trusted root CA certificate?

Comment: did you try to install the certificate? I did a quick search and found for example this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-essentials-and/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in/ba-p/396105

Comment: ... and this https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1839-installing-self-signed-ca-certificate-in-windows

Comment: We wanted to avoid installing it into the Windows Trust Store because this requires our application to run with or elevate to admin privileges, which might not be available for all users running our application. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Clemens Did you solve this? Having the same problem even though I added the root ca using the Microsoft Management Console (mmc).

Comment: @Magnus Sadly no, we are sticking to the Indy HTTP Client for now.